# Cannot SSH/SFTP to remote server without using another remote server

Tags: nautilus, ssh, sftp

I can access a server *A* with SSH, and from there I can access server *B*, but I can't access *B* directly.

Is it possible to open a Nautilus folder in server *B* by clicking in `Places` → `Connect to Server`?

Comment: Quick question... in relation to server 'A', where is server 'B'?  On an internal network which Server 'A' shares with Server 'B', or on a separate external network/IP?  Also, is Server 'B' restricting connections to it to a selected group of IPs, say the iP that Server A has?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is possible. 
I have the following setup which works, but there might be easier ones.

In the file `~/.ssh/config`, add the following lines:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath   /home/yourusername/.ssh/tmp/%h_%p_%r
Host A
  HostName hostname.of.server.a

Host B
  ProxyCommand ssh -e none A netcat -w 5 hostname.of.server.b 22
```

You have to replace yourusername, hostname.of.sever.a and hostname.of.server.b
After that, you can (in Nautilus) go to Places->Connect to Server (its actually File->Connect to Server on my machine). And then enter `B`.
That should be all to see the server B.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to try is to add this to .ssh/config:

```
Host B
  ProxyCommand ssh A nc -q0 %h %p
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Once this is in place, you should be able to `ssh B` directly, and SSH will know to "bounce" the connection through A first.

When this is working, try Nautilus the way you describe and see if the proxying setup works for it as well.

Comment: I can't post comments yet so I'm writing here. roadmr reply worked perfectly for me but I had to change "-q0" with "-p0". Looking at the man nc, -q should be the waiting time and -p should specify the source port. I don't know why that should be 0, but it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

An update on the previous answers: using netcat to forward the connection on the intermediate host works differently than ssh'ing directly, and will fail when you want to e.g. connect to a VNC server that is set to only accept local connections through a jumphost tunnel. In order for the connection to work exactly like a direct one, use the -W option present in newer versions of the client:

```
Host jumphost
Hostname hostname.of.jumphost

Host target
Hostname hostname.of.target
Port 30022
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost
```

Comment: Worked fine for me! The solution with netcat requires it to be installed in the jumphost (it wasn't in my case and I didn't have permission to install).